# kendo/breeze error : The 'query' parameter must be an instance of 'EntityQuery', or it must be a 'string'

Tags: kendo-ui, breeze

When using `kendo.data.extensions.BreezeDataSource`, this error appears :

> The 'query' parameter  must be an instance of 'EntityQuery', or it must be a 'string'

This is my code :

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.extensions.BreezeDataSource({
        entityManager: manager,
        endPoint: "Clients",
        serverSorting: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 10
});
```

Please advise.